# tm and Snowball package commands slow in Linux

Tags: linux, windows, r, tm, snowball

I am using tm and Snowball packages in R for text mining. I initially ran it on my laptop that has Windows 7 with 8 GB memory. Later I tried the same on a Linux (Ubuntu) machine with 64 GB of memory. Both of these machines are 64 bit and am using 64 bit version of R as well. However, **Windows has R 3.0.0 whereas Linux has R 2.14**

Some of the commands are extremely slow in Linux when compared to Windows.

**Corpus Command**

**On windows**

```
    d <- data.frame(chatTranscripts$chatConcat)
    ds <- DataframeSource(d)
    t1 <- Sys.time()
    dsc<-Corpus(ds)
    print(Sys.time() - t1)
    Time difference of 46.86169 secs
```

This took only 47 secs on the Windows machine

**On Linux**

```
    t1 <- Sys.time()
    dsc<-Corpus(ds)
    print(Sys.time() - t1)
    Time difference of 3.674376 mins
```

This took around **220 secs** on the Linux machine

**Snowball Stemming**

**On windows**

```
    t1 <- Sys.time()
    dsc <- tm_map(dsc,stemDocument)
    print(Sys.time() - t1)
    Time difference of 12.05321 secs
```

This took only **12 secs** on the Windows machine

**On Linux**

```
    t1 <- Sys.time()
    dsc <- tm_map(dsc,stemDocument)
    print(Sys.time() - t1)
    Time difference of 4.832964 mins
```

This took around **290 secs** on the Linux machine

Is there a way to speed these commands on the Linux machine? Will the R versions make such a big difference. Thank you.

Ravi

Comment: It's possible that the R version could make a difference.  There were some really big performance improvements in how R handles data frames in v2.15.1, a result of work by Tim Hesterberg.  See http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/06/r-2151-dataframe-package.html

Answer (score 0):

`Corpus()` on `VectorSource()` seems to be faster than `Corpus()` on `DataframeSource()`.

You can try

```
d <- chatTranscripts$chatConcat
ds <- VectorSource(d)
Corpus(ds)
```